# Pick out the correct choices -TIFR 2015

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $f:\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R$ be a continuous function and $A \subset \mathbb R$ be defined by $A=\{y \in \mathbb R:y=\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty}f(x_n),$for some sequence  $x_n\rightarrow \infty\}$

Then the set $A$ is necessarily

A.a connected set

B.compact set

C. a singleton set

D.None of above

Now since $f$ is a continuous function and $x_n$ diverges so $f(x_n)$ will also diverge.Hence the set can't be bounded and hence not compact

Also it may not be singleton as $f(x_n)$ may be either $\infty$ or -$\infty$

Not sure with A.Can someone please check my solution and suggest required edits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Continuous functions take convergent sequences to convergent sequences, but you can't say the same for divergent sequences. For instance, consider a constant function. For a better example, which will also give a hint for how to solve your problem, take $f(x) = \sin(x)$. For a still better example, think of how you could modify this $f$ to change the set $A$...

Comment: May be $x_n=n\pi$ divergent but $f(x_n)$ is not.But I did not get what you are asking about modification

Comment: @learnmore: if $f(x)=\sin(x)$, then $A=[-1,1]$, which is both compact and connected. But if you modify $f$ slightly, you can make $A$ non-compact. Think about that for an hour or two before coming straight back with "I don't get it".

Comment: can u please give some more hints about the modification @TonyK

Comment: @learnmore: I said an hour or two, not half an hour. Put some effort in.

Comment: should I modify $f$ such that its image becomes $[-1,1)$ or $(-1,1]$ which is not closed and hence not compact @TonyK

Comment: @learnmore: No, I don't think that is possible (because $A$ contains its limit points, and is therefore closed). Think of a closed set that is not compact.

Comment: that means an unbounded set right but image of sin function can't be unbounded right?? @TonyK

Comment: Unbounded, yes. As hunter says, think of how you could _modify_ this $f$ to make it unbounded.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is connected,as far as I think.Because take the function $f(x)=e^xsinx$ where $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ ,for this function the set $A$ is neither compact nor singleton.Again consider $f$ which is continuous.Let $y_1<y_2\in A$,then let $y$ be in between them.Now there exists $(a_n),(b_n)\to \infty$ such that $f(a_n)=y_1$ and $f(b_n)=y_2$.Now since $y_1<y_2$ then there exists $N$ such that $f(a_n)<y<f(b_n)$ for all $n>N$.Now there exists a sequence $(c_n)$ such that $a_n<c_n<b_n \forall n>N$,and $f(c_n)=y\forall n>N$.Then $\operatorname{lim}f(c_n)=y$ and by sandwich theorem $c_n \to \infty$ as $n\to \infty$.So $y\in A$.